# (Unity) I cannot drag my UI components in my GameManager

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

[UI components and GameManager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrXQm.png)

I'm following a video tutorial on Unity and the person just dragged those items in the GameManager slots, what I am not able to do.
Code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject ballPrefab;
    public GameObject PlayerPrefab;
    public Text scoreText;
    public Text ballsText;
    public Text levelText;

    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the inspector of e.g. `TextScore`?

Comment: Oh wait, in your picture did you select the `GameManager` inside your Hierachy or inside your project folder?

Comment: I was selecting the script in the project folder instead of the Hierarchy.. Thanks a lot! I've neved felt this dumb in my life lol.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you selected the `GameManager` inside your project folder and not inside your hierachy. Thats why you can drag & drop `Prefabs` inside of it but not your `Text` inside your hierachy.